# IPv6 reader in Python

Tags: python, flask, server, ip

I have a small Python code to read the IP address of the client visiting my Flask website, hosted on pythonanywhere.com:

```
from flask import Flask, request 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    ipread1 = request.environ.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP', request.remote_addr)
    print("The client IP1 is: %s" % (ipread1))
    return 'Hello  World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This correctly returns my IPv4 address in the server log each time I refresh the webpage. However, I would like it to instead give out my IPv6 address (which I've already checked that I do have).

To do this, I have tried changing:

`app.run()` to `app.run(host='::')`

But this still just gives my IPv4 address. How can I force Python to give my IPv6 address?

Comment: To get the IPv6 address, the peer has to connect via IPv6.

Comment: Is there a way to force a connection via IPv6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All requests processed by PythonAnywhere come through IPv4, so you won't see an IPv6 address.

Comment: Ahhh now this is something I wasn't aware of. Certainly explains it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the first case with `app.run()`. What you get is a IPV4 address of the client such as:

```
The client IP1 is: 127.0.0.1
```

Now, if You add the argument host `app.run(host='::')` you listen on the IPv6 socket and get something like:

```
The client IP1 is: ::ffff:127.0.0.1
```

*Is the client using IPv6?*
No, the client is still using its IPv4 address and talking with an IPv4 server. So, no diffference from its point of view. What changes is that you get `v4-mapped-on-v6 address` with the following form:

```
000 ... 000 |   FFFF  | IPv4 Address
   80 bits    16 bits     32 bits
```

See for example the corresponding [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291).

In such a way, from the point of view of the server it will look like it comes from an IPv6 host and it would be able to use a dual-stack IPv4/IPv6.

If you want to see something different, you have to change the way your client send its requests.

Comment: Thank you for your response, and whilst it was useful, this has not yet solved my problem. I am looking for my unique IPv6 address, rather than a conversion of my IPv4 address to the IPv6 format. For example, if I visit whatip.me, this shows me my unique IPv6 address - this is what I would like to read in Python.